# High level Consumer api lifecycle for Kafka 0.8

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I can't find lifecycle description for High level consumer. I'm on 0.8.2.2 and I can't use "modern" consumer from kafka-clients. Here is my code:

```
def consume(numberOfEvents: Int, await: Duration = 100.millis): List[MessageEnvelope] = {
    val consumerProperties = new Properties()
    consumerProperties.put("zookeeper.connect", kafkaConfig.zooKeeperConnectString)
    consumerProperties.put("group.id", consumerGroup)
    consumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest")

    val consumer = Consumer.create(new ConsumerConfig(consumerProperties))

    try {
      val messageStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(
        Predef.Map(kafkaConfig.topic -> 1),
        new DefaultDecoder,
        new MessageEnvelopeDecoder)

      val receiveMessageFuture = Future[List[MessageEnvelope]] {
        messageStreams(kafkaConfig.topic)
          .flatMap(stream => stream.take(numberOfEvents).map(_.message()))
      }

      Await.result(receiveMessageFuture, await)
    } finally {
      consumer.shutdown()
    }
```

It's not clear to me. Should I shutdown consumer after each message retrieval or I can keep instance and reuse it for message fetching? I suppose reusing instance is the right way, but can't find some articles / best practices.

I'm trying to reuse consumer and / or messageStreams. It doesn't work well for me and I can't find the reason for it.

If I try to reuse messageStreams, I get exception:

```
2017-04-17_19:57:57.088 ERROR MessageEnvelopeConsumer - Error while awaiting for messages java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterator is in failed state
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterator is in failed state
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.take(IterableLike.scala:134)
    at kafka.consumer.KafkaStream.take(KafkaStream.scala:25)
```

Happens here:

```
def consume(numberOfEvents: Int, await: Duration = 100.millis): List[MessageEnvelope] = {
    try {
      val receiveMessageFuture = Future[List[MessageEnvelope]] {
        messageStreams(kafkaConfig.topic)
          .flatMap(stream => stream.take(numberOfEvents).map(_.message()))
      }
      Try(Await.result(receiveMessageFuture, await)) match {
        case Success(result) => result
        case Failure(_: TimeoutException) => List.empty
        case Failure(e) =>
          // ===> never got any message from topic
          logger.error(s"Error while awaiting for messages ${e.getClass.getName}: ${e.getMessage}", e)
          List.empty

      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.warn(s"Error while consuming messages", e)
        List.empty
    }
  }
```

I tried to create messageStreams each time:

no luck...

```
2017-04-17_20:02:44.236 WARN  MessageEnvelopeConsumer - Error while consuming messages
kafka.common.MessageStreamsExistException: ZookeeperConsumerConnector can create message streams at most once
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:151)
    at MessageEnvelopeConsumer.consume(MessageEnvelopeConsumer.scala:47)
```

Happens here:

```
def consume(numberOfEvents: Int, await: Duration = 100.millis): List[MessageEnvelope] = {
    try {

      val messageStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(
        Predef.Map(kafkaConfig.topic -> 1),
        new DefaultDecoder,
        new MessageEnvelopeDecoder)

      val receiveMessageFuture = Future[List[MessageEnvelope]] {
        messageStreams(kafkaConfig.topic)
          .flatMap(stream => stream.take(numberOfEvents).map(_.message()))
      }
      Try(Await.result(receiveMessageFuture, await)) match {
        case Success(result) => result
        case Failure(_: TimeoutException) => List.empty
        case Failure(e) =>
          logger.error(s"Error while awaiting for messages ${e.getClass.getName}: ${e.getMessage}", e)
          List.empty

      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        // ===> now exception raised here
        logger.warn(s"Error while consuming messages", e)
        List.empty
    }
  }
```

**UPD**

I used iterator based approach. It looks this way:

```
// consumerProperties.put("consumer.timeout.ms", "100")    

private lazy val consumer: ConsumerConnector = Consumer.create(new ConsumerConfig(consumerProperties))

  private lazy val messageStreams: Seq[KafkaStream[Array[Byte], MessageEnvelope]] =
    consumer.createMessageStreamsByFilter(Whitelist(kafkaConfig.topic), 1, new DefaultDecoder, new MessageEnvelopeDecoder)


  private lazy val iterator: ConsumerIterator[Array[Byte], MessageEnvelope] = {
    val stream = messageStreams.head
    stream.iterator()
  }

  def consume(): List[MessageEnvelope] = {
    try {
      if (iterator.hasNext) {
        val fromKafka: MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte], MessageEnvelope] = iterator.next
        List(fromKafka.message())
      } else {
        List.empty
      }

    } catch {
      case _: ConsumerTimeoutException =>
        List.empty

      case e: Exception =>
        logger.warn(s"Error while consuming messages", e)
        List.empty
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to figure out if it automatically commits offsets to ZK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is the latest question update. Iterator approach works for me as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Constant shutdown causes unnecessary consumer group rebalances which affects the performance a lot. See this article for best practices: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Comment: Hi, tried to implement your approach. Met other problem. Could you check my update please?

Comment: So, it works as "expected" (messages fetched) only in one case: when I create consumer, messageStreams, fetch message and close consumer.